# Picker Label Changing to selected value SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, picker

[image: I want a constant label here , but my picker label is changing upon the value I select]

I want a constant label here , but my picker label is changing upon the value I select.

My Code :

```
Picker(
                        selection : $textBoxes[currentIndex].textFont,
                        label : Text("Font"),
                        content : {
                            Text("LuxuriousRoman-Regular").tag("LuxuriousRoman-Regular")
                            Text("Merriweather-Regular").tag("Merriweather-Regular")
                            Text("Neonderthaw-Regular").tag("Neonderthaw-Regular")
                            Text("OpenSansCondensed-Light").tag("OpenSansCondensed-Light")
                            Text("Pacifico").tag("Pacifico")
                            Text("PTSans-Regular").tag("PTSans-Regular")
                            Text("RobotoMono-VariableFont_wght").tag("RobotoMono-VariableFont_wght")
                            Text("SedgwickAve-Regular").tag("SedgwickAve-Regular")
                        }
                    ).pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `Picker` in its menu style form, the `label` doesn't get displayed, and instead the selected item is used, as you've seen.

If you want a standard label to be used, you should use `Menu` as the base view, and then use a `Picker` as the menu's contents. For example you can see the difference in usage here:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  enum DemoOption: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three, four, five
  }
  
  @State private var pickerValue: DemoOption = .one
  @State private var menuValue: DemoOption = .two
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Picker("Picker Option", selection: $pickerValue) {
        ForEach(DemoOption.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { option in
          Text(option.rawValue).tag(option)
        }
      }
      .pickerStyle(.menu)
      
      Menu {
        Picker("Choose an option", selection: $menuValue) {
          ForEach(DemoOption.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { option in
            Text(option.rawValue).tag(option)
          }
        }
      } label: {
        Text("Choose an option")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]